# Using Layout with JMSAppender in Logback

Tags: logback

I am using a JMSAppender from the Logback framework to write messages to a Websphere MQ.We have a custom Layout class and have specified it in the config file.However, the layout is not being applied. I read that the JMS appender doesn't really use a Layout class.Is there a way on how I can apply a Layout for the JMSAppender.

Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might be a bit late and you might have figured it out already ....

i was doing some work on `JMSAppender` lately. 
logs are sent to queues as `ObjectMessage` of type `LoggingEventVO` which is basically a serializable view of a log entry. you have everything that you need in this instance so a layout/encoder would be irrelevant. On the log consumer side you cast the message to the correct type and produce any format you like there

Take a look at [LoggingEventVO src](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/LoggingEventVO.java)